# How to save all fields of a Rails record even if they are not changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails attributes API for encrypting and decrypting certain fields when the record is saved/loaded to/from database. Now I needed to change the way the encryption is done and need to re-save all records so that the encrypted value in the database gets updated.

But this seems really hard after partial_updates configuration was removed in Rails 4. Is there any way to make Rails save the fields even though they have not changed?

Or do I need to write a method that does a direct SQL update?

Comment: how many records in the table ?

Comment: There are like 400k records.

Comment: you can make a rake task and load bulks of record from the table , make the update , then save until you update every record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to mark them as dirty. For example the Post model has a `title` attribute:

```
post = Post.find(12)
post.title_will_change!
post.save
```

See [here for more information on dirty attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).